# Jquery Unobtrusive Validation 'Cannot read property 'type' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation in my MVC application.  When posting back, the validation works as-prescribed.  However, there are valid reasons for me to prevent a post-back client-side.

I am following the prescribed approach seen across multiple sites...and I have tried many different combinations.  However, I still keep getting the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT LOOKS LIKE:**
The error happens when I call 'showErrors'...

```
function onValidateCity(e){

    // Checks the value of my Kendo Combobox
    var value = this.value();
    if (value && this.selectedIndex === -1) {

        // Yes, it reaches this part
        var validator = $('#CityId').validate();
        validator.showErrors({"CityId": "My custom error message!"});
    }
}
```

**MY MVC HELPER CREATES THE FOLLOWING HTML:**

```
<span class="k-widget k-combobox k-header form-control">
    <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
        <input name="CityId_input" class="k-input form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="" maxlength="524288" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="-- Select City --" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="CityId_listbox" aria-busy="false" style="width: 100%;" /> 
        <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="CityId_listbox">select</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The City field is required." id="CityId" name="CityId" type="text" value=  "28dbddea-660d-4bbb-b063-f926b1153866" data-role="combobox" aria-disabled="false"
aria-readonly="false" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;" />
</span>

<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CityId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

**MVC (VALIDATION) HELPER LOOKS LIKE:** 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: At first glance you don't have an element with `id="CityId"`. Look like your validator simply didn't initialize. Add `id="CityId"` to your `input` element.

Comment: Look next to the "data-val-required" attribute...thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the second input. Touche.  Trying to reproduce the issue in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `validator`, do it against the element that contains `CityId` input nested inside, not the input element itself. It can be a `form` or a `div` or a `span`.

Here's simplified code working in fiddle, I did it against `span`:
**http://jsfiddle.net/o0qhcbbL/1/**

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    onValidateCity(e)
})

function onValidateCity(e) {

    var validator = $('#xx').validate();

    validator.showErrors({
        "CityId": "My custom error message!"
    });
}
```

html:

```
<span id="xx">
    <input id="CityId" name="CityId" type="text" />
</span>
<span id="button">select</span>
```

Comment: I did try this in previous efforts, but it simply 'flashes' the message to the screen...and then...empties the message from the 'displaying element'.  In fact, it does it so fast you cannot even see the message unless you put a break-point on in the javascript.

Comment: You would never attach the `.validate()` method to an `input`, `div`, or `span`.  The `.validate()` method only gets attached to the `form` element and that's already being done automatically by the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.

Comment: Okay...cool...I get that now...thanks.  So...why does the message disappear the moment the JavaScript function completes?